# SpringBoot @RequestMapping & handle thread

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, request-mapping

I wrote a simple @RequestMapping in spring boot without any additional configuration. Just sleep 20s for every visit.

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() throws InterruptedException {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + ": sleep begin");
        Thread.sleep(20_000);
        System.out.println(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + ": sleep end");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

And a visit `http://localhost:8080/hello` in five tabs in Chrome continuously, I expecte console logs like:

```
sleep begin
sleep begin
sleep begin
sleep begin
sleep begin
sleep end
sleep end
sleep end
sleep end
sleep end
```

But actually it shows:

```
2021-02-10 14:30:35: sleep begin
2021-02-10 14:30:55: sleep end
2021-02-10 14:30:55: sleep begin
2021-02-10 14:30:57: sleep begin
2021-02-10 14:30:59: sleep begin
2021-02-10 14:31:00: sleep begin
2021-02-10 14:31:15: sleep end
2021-02-10 14:31:17: sleep end
2021-02-10 14:31:19: sleep end
2021-02-10 14:31:20: sleep end
```

So, I wander how SpringBoot handle @RequestMapping, seems it's not single thread nor simple multi thread.

Answer (score 0):

And if I just use one Chrome tab, visit once and refresh four times, it acted as I expected. So it may be Chrome optimization: to let same request in a row one by one.